# Returning unknown number of values from a function prototype

Tags: c++

I am a beginner programmer in C++. I am trying to create a function prototype that returns the factors of a number. However, all the methods I have seen for returning multiple values from a function prototype require knowing in advance the number of values that will be returned, which is not possible for factorisation.

What I did in Python was:

```
def findfac(n):
    factors = [1, n]   # Make an array
    i = 2.0
    while i < n:
        if i not in factors and (n/i).is_integer():
            factors += [i, n/i]
        i += 1
    return factors
```

This returns an array containing all the factors of n.

The issue is that while I can just dump an indefinite number of elements into a Python array, C++ arrays have a maximum size. So is there a way to return a dynamic array in C++, or should I rethink my approach?

Comment: Returning a pointer (as long as it's dynamically allocated with something from the `malloc()` family) should be fine, but the length would be unknown, unless that's possibly an argument to the function (as a pointer) that gets populated with the size, too. Try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> findfac(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> factors{1, n}; // factors = [1, n]
    int i;
    // TODO
    factors.push_back(i); // factors = [1, n, ..., i]
    // TODO
    return factors; // factors = [factors of n...]
}
```

---

[`std::vector::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), [`std::vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)

Comment: I'm getting these errors:

`error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|`
`error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::vector<int>]'|`

Comment: @thequantumforge you can't output a vector directly. you have to output each element individually: `for (int i : factors) { std::cout << i << '\n'; }`